# Encryption with Android 4.2 and earlier versions - PRNGFixes

Tags: android, security, prng

I need to encrypt password, but for Android 4.2 and below version, my solution doesn't work, The encrypted password is random. it's due to PRNG. So I saw this post :

https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html

I implemented PRNGFixes, but it does not change...

How to solve this problem of randomly generated number ?

Code :

```
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray(), byteSalt, NB_ITER_RFC, SIZE_KEY);
SecretKey temp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(DES_EDE_PKCS5);
IvParameterSpec ivParam = new IvParameterSpec(bytesIv);
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, temp, ivParam);
byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(texteAChiffrer.getBytes("UTF-8"));
mdp = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

OR :

```
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray(), byteSalt, NB_ITER_RFC, SIZE_KEY);
byte[] key2 = PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(pbeKeySpec.getPassword());
SecretKey temp2 = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
Cipher c2 = Cipher.getInstance(DES_EDE_PKCS5);
c2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, temp2, ivParam);
byte[] encrypted2 = c2.doFinal(texteAChiffrer.getBytes("UTF-8"));       
mdp = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted2, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

This two solutions give the same results from Android 4.3 and latest versions (4.4 and 5.0)

Thank you for your help :)